# Call a method/function with arguments from json object dynamically

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON object as follows

```
var jsonData = {
    getData1:function(id1, id2){
    },
    getData2:function(id1, id2){
    }
};
```

I have a `method name` (eg: getData1) & `arguments` (id1, id2) in `separate variables`. these are dynamic.

Manually I can call the method as follows

```
jsonData.getData1(id1, id2);
```

but I want to call a method dynamically with passing 2 arguments (id1, id2). what is the correct way to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that `jsonData.getData1` is just a shortcut for `jsonData['getData1']`, but in the latter version, what you put inside the square brackets can be any expression, not just a literal. So you can do:

```
var methodName = "getData1";
jsonData[methodName](id1, id2);
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be a case for the call method attached to every function.

```
jsonData[methodName].call(id1, id2)
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, an object's properties can be accessed easily via array notation as well. So, in your case:

```
jsonData.getData1(id1, id2);
```

and

```
jsonData['getData1'](id1, id2);
```

behave in the same way.
You can also do:

```
var methodName = document.getElementById('methodNameInput').value;
jsonData[methodName](id1, id2);
```

`methodName` just needs to be a string.

More:

```
var ob = {
   foo: 'hello',
   bar: function(x) {
     return x+'!';
   }
 };

 console.log(ob['foo'] + ' ' + ob['bar']('world'));   // prints "hello world!"
 console.log(ob.foo + ' ' + ob.bar('world'));         // prints "hello word!"
```